# Call functions present in the java script of webpage into android app

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

How to call functions present in the java script of webpage into android app.I want to show results returned by this functions inside android app.

For example getTalukas function returns list of Strings.I want to show it in android app.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var PageMethods = function() {
PageMethods.initializeBase(this);
this._timeout = 0;
this._userContext = null;
this._succeeded = null;
this._failed = null;
}
PageMethods.prototype = {
_get_path:function() {
 var p = this.get_path();
 if (p) return p;
 else return PageMethods._staticInstance.get_path();},
getTalukas:function(id,succeededCallback, failedCallback, userContext) {
return this._invoke(this._get_path(), 'getTalukas',false,{id:id},succeededCallback,failedCallback,userContext); },
getVillages:function(did,tid,succeededCallback, failedCallback, userContext) {
return this._invoke(this._get_path(), 'getVillages',false,{did:did,tid:tid},succeededCallback,failedCallback,userContext); },
getKnos:function(ptxt,vid,did,tid,succeededCallback, failedCallback, userContext) {
return this._invoke(this._get_path(), 'getKnos',false,{ptxt:ptxt,vid:vid,did:did,tid:tid},succeededCallback,failedCallback,userContext); },
getSnos:function(ptxt,vid,did,tid,succeededCallback, failedCallback, userContext) {
return this._invoke(this._get_path(), 'getSnos',false,{ptxt:ptxt,vid:vid,did:did,tid:tid},succeededCallback,failedCallback,userContext); },
getKnames:function(ptxt,vid,opt,did,tid,succeededCallback, failedCallback, userContext) {
return this._invoke(this._get_path(), 'getKnames',false,{ptxt:ptxt,vid:vid,opt:opt,did:did,tid:tid},succeededCallback,failedCallback,userContext); },
getSnames:function(ptxt,vid,opt,did,tid,succeededCallback, failedCallback, userContext) {
return this._invoke(this._get_path(), 'getSnames',false,{ptxt:ptxt,vid:vid,opt:opt,did:did,tid:tid},succeededCallback,failedCallback,userContext); },
call8a:function(kno,vid,dn,tn,vn,did,tid,succeededCallback, failedCallback, userContext) {
return this._invoke(this._get_path(), 'call8a',false,{kno:kno,vid:vid,dn:dn,tn:tn,vn:vn,did:did,tid:tid},succeededCallback,failedCallback,userContext); },
call712:function(sno,vid,dn,tn,vn,tc,dc,did,tid,succeededCallback, failedCallback, userContext) {
return this._invoke(this._get_path(), 'call712',false,{sno:sno,vid:vid,dn:dn,tn:tn,vn:vn,tc:tc,dc:dc,did:did,tid:tid},succeededCallback,failedCallback,userContext); },
getCTSOs:function(id,succeededCallback, failedCallback, userContext) {
return this._invoke(this._get_path(), 'getCTSOs',false,{id:id},succeededCallback,failedCallback,userContext); },
getCTSOLink:function(did,tid,succeededCallback, failedCallback, userContext) {
return this._invoke(this._get_path(), 'getCTSOLink',false,{did:did,tid:tid},succeededCallback,failedCallback,userContext); }}
PageMethods.registerClass('PageMethods',Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy);
PageMethods._staticInstance = new PageMethods();
PageMethods.set_path = function(value) { PageMethods._staticInstance.set_path(value); }
PageMethods.get_path = function() { return PageMethods._staticInstance.get_path(); }
PageMethods.set_timeout = function(value) { PageMethods._staticInstance.set_timeout(value); }
PageMethods.get_timeout = function() { return PageMethods._staticInstance.get_timeout(); }
PageMethods.set_defaultUserContext = function(value) { PageMethods._staticInstance.set_defaultUserContext(value); }
PageMethods.get_defaultUserContext = function() { return PageMethods._staticInstance.get_defaultUserContext(); }
PageMethods.set_defaultSucceededCallback = function(value) { PageMethods._staticInstance.set_defaultSucceededCallback(value); }
PageMethods.get_defaultSucceededCallback = function() { return PageMethods._staticInstance.get_defaultSucceededCallback(); }
PageMethods.set_defaultFailedCallback = function(value) { PageMethods._staticInstance.set_defaultFailedCallback(value); }
PageMethods.get_defaultFailedCallback = function() { return PageMethods._staticInstance.get_defaultFailedCallback(); }
PageMethods.set_enableJsonp = function(value) { PageMethods._staticInstance.set_enableJsonp(value); }
PageMethods.get_enableJsonp = function() { return PageMethods._staticInstance.get_enableJsonp(); }
PageMethods.set_jsonpCallbackParameter = function(value) { PageMethods._staticInstance.set_jsonpCallbackParameter(value); }
PageMethods.get_jsonpCallbackParameter = function() { return PageMethods._staticInstance.get_jsonpCallbackParameter(); }
PageMethods.set_path("Home.aspx");
PageMethods.getTalukas= function(id,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext) {PageMethods._staticInstance.getTalukas(id,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext); }
PageMethods.getVillages= function(did,tid,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext) {PageMethods._staticInstance.getVillages(did,tid,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext); }
PageMethods.getKnos= function(ptxt,vid,did,tid,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext) {PageMethods._staticInstance.getKnos(ptxt,vid,did,tid,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext); }
PageMethods.getSnos= function(ptxt,vid,did,tid,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext) {PageMethods._staticInstance.getSnos(ptxt,vid,did,tid,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext); }
PageMethods.getKnames= function(ptxt,vid,opt,did,tid,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext) {PageMethods._staticInstance.getKnames(ptxt,vid,opt,did,tid,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext); }
PageMethods.getSnames= function(ptxt,vid,opt,did,tid,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext) {PageMethods._staticInstance.getSnames(ptxt,vid,opt,did,tid,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext); }
PageMethods.call8a= function(kno,vid,dn,tn,vn,did,tid,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext) {PageMethods._staticInstance.call8a(kno,vid,dn,tn,vn,did,tid,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext); }
PageMethods.call712= function(sno,vid,dn,tn,vn,tc,dc,did,tid,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext) {PageMethods._staticInstance.call712(sno,vid,dn,tn,vn,tc,dc,did,tid,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext); }
PageMethods.getCTSOs= function(id,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext) {PageMethods._staticInstance.getCTSOs(id,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext); }
PageMethods.getCTSOLink= function(did,tid,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext) {PageMethods._staticInstance.getCTSOLink(did,tid,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext); }
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is that you can create functions within your app that can be called from JavaScript (note: be careful with this or you can create a security problem)

The example below is taken from https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Key parts:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Main program:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

HTML page:

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
```

Comment: Awesome way.but I don't want any modification with site, just want to get the way in which I can do it with current code of website.

Answer (score 0):

How about `http request` from the app to the page 
and the page return `json`.

Comment: I am Aware about it.but, I want to explore new way for doing this without http requests.

Comment: how about using firebase

Comment: thank you for suggestion,but I want the solution in the way in which I have mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

May be Web view JavaScript Bridge is what you are looking for! You can use this [JSBridge](https://github.com/lzyzsd/JsBridge) or implement JS bridge on your own.